# Communicate with APNS server over HTTP2 in Swift2

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift2, http2

does anyone know how to use the new APNS provider API from Apple that was introduced in a Session of the WWDC2015? For my tests I used PushMeBaby(a OpenSource Push server from github). But this little App won't work anymore in the future. has someone implemented a HTTP2 client in Swift yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using this Code from [Github](https://github.com/alexeyxo/swift-apns).

For me it's actually easier to use the `APNSNetwork` Class directly, so i don't have to mess up with Carthage.

The Class is very easy to use and available for Swift2 and Swift3.

I hope this will help you in your Project **;-)**

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple has still not released any information regarding the new APNS HTTP/2 service, or even anything regarding when information will become available.

Most developers seem to be eager to make the switch to the new endpoints, but we will all have to wait for the time being.